# Add Document Data to Chapter Title

Tags: scrivener

I'm writing a story using Scrivener. To keep track of the story timeline, I currently write the (fictional) time and date of the happenings of each scene in the Document Notes section.

I'm considering including that time and date as part of the chapter title, to help the reader follow the timeline. Is there a way to do that in Scrivener short of moving the information from Document Notes to the body of the text?

I looked at the available placeholder tags in Appendix D of the manual, but don't see anything suitable.

Comment: This is a software question that probably belongs in http://superuser.com/

Comment: @rolfedh: Most of the questions tagged Scrivener here are about use of the program. There is no Scrivener tag on superuser.

Comment: Scrivener questions are [on-topic here](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/276/26), since it's a speciality writing tool.

Comment: FrameMaker is a specialty writing tool, but a question about it was migrated to SuperUser recently. http://superuser.com/questions/1014547/find-change-in-framemaker-does-not-recognize-linked-words
The tags should exist where the questions belong, not the other way around. This is a question for Meta!

Comment: I have not used FrameMaker but it seems more like Word (software for people with something to write) and less like Scrivener (software for writers). That seems to be the distinction that was made in meta. If my presumption is incorrect, the migration to SuperUser may have been incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom meta-data tags for the date and time information.

To get this information into the chapter headings, insert the meta data in the chapter heading in compile, using the `<$custom:TAGNAME>`-tag (where TAGNAME is the name of the custom meta-data tag).

To work with this information in regular editing, add the meta data as columns in the outline view.

Here's a more detailed discussion of headers in Scrivener: [3 Minutes to Better Scrivener Chapter Headings](https://genelempp.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/3-minutes-to-better-scrivener-chapter-headings/)